# The distances on totally geodesic submanifold and manifold.

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, submanifold

There is a conlusion that the distances on a totally geodesic submanifold $M^{n} \subseteq N^{n+p}$ are the same with the distances on $N^{n+p}$(if we need we can add completeness). But I do not know how to prove it(Seems to be obvious)? Is there any proof or references about the question?

Comment: What is the definition you consider for totally geodesic?

Comment: @Didier In the general means. The second fundemental form vanished.

Comment: Then show that a geodesic in $N$ is in fact a geodesic in $M$ thanks to the equality $\nabla^M_{\gamma'}\gamma' = \nabla^N_{\gamma'}\gamma' + II(\gamma',\gamma')$. If $N$ is complete, the distances are thus the same.

Comment: Are you sure the conclusion is true?

Comment: You're totally right, we cannot conclude anything about the distances

Comment: This is a nice question. And I fell in the trap until @JasonDeVito alerted me. Of course, we have a geodesic that stays in $M$, but no one says it's the shortest one joining the points in $N$. Perhaps Jason should write an answer. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin:  Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above, this is not true as stated.

Perhaps the simplest counterexample is the following.  Let $N = S^1\times S^1$ be a flat torus, with each circle factor of total length $1$.  Envisioning this as square with sides identified, it is easy to see that it has diameter $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

Now, for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, consider the geodesic $\gamma_k:[0,1]\rightarrow N$ with $\gamma_k(t) = (t, kt)$.  Then $\|\gamma'(t)\| = \sqrt{1+k^2}$.   By inspecting the first coordinate, it is clear that $\gamma_k$ is injective, except that $\gamma_k(0) = \gamma_k(1)$.  In particular, the length of $\gamma_k$ is $\sqrt{1+k^2}$.

Take $N$ to be the image of $\gamma_k$, which is a totally geodesic submanifold of $M$.  From the calcuation in the previous paragraph, we see that $d_N(\gamma_k(0),\gamma_k(1/2)) = \frac{\sqrt{1+k^2}}{2}$.  For $|k| > 2$, it now follows that $d_N(\gamma_k(0),\gamma_k(1/2)) > d_M(\gamma_k(0), \gamma_k(1/2)).$

Comment: Ah, very nice. I was thinking about alteringing the Euclidean metric in $\Bbb R^3$ off a fixed plane to make a shorter path by venturing off the plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin:  I also like your example, because it gives examples where the totally geodesic submanifold can have arbitrary dimension and codimension.  And, for people like me who prefer compact spaces, one can just adapt Ted's example to lie in $T^k$.